# MariaDB unkown syntax error in loop procedure

Tags: sql, mariadb

We have a web server along with databases for websites. I run this code in phpmyadmin on database with MariaDB 10.3.38 but i get an error i dont understand. I tried eveything i could within my knowledge.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 150000 THEN
        UPDATE `mw_list_field_value`
        SET value = 'Κρήτη'
        WHERE field_id = 146;
        ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
END;
```

and i get this error:
 `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4`

I tried removing the update command inside the if,

Comment: Try running your query directly on the DB to see what the syntax issue is.  It says LINE 4 so it is probably the last line of your query.